# While Opening STS I am getting error Dialogue

Tags: java, spring

[image]

Can anybody give some pointers as to why I am getting this error.

Comment: You might want to remove c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath from your windows path variable. If needed, add the correct path to javaw.exe.

Comment: Please add java path in your system

Comment: @Burkhard wow Ur Awesome....It worked Thanks alot

Comment: It was just a lucky guess :) Since it worked, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Eclipse after an update of Java.

It helped to remove `c:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` from the Windows path variable. If needed, add the correct path to javaw.exe.